# Mutating table issue in after row trigger

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, package, triggers, mutating-table

I've created a package that contains one procedure and one function.
Function is called by the trigger on insert after each row on the table REZULTAT.

```
create or replace trigger rezultat_compound
for insert on rezultat
compound trigger
 v_igid              rezultat.igra_id%type;
 v_reid              rezultat.id%type;
 v_jck               rezultat.jocker_broj%type;
 cursor cur_type is  rezultat%rowtype;
before each row is
begin
 v_reid:=rezultat_seq.nextval;
 :new.id:=v_reid;
 v_igid:=:new.igra_id;
end before each row;

after each row is
begin
 v_jck:=loto_7_47_pck.getJockerBroj(v_igid);
end after each row;

end rezultat_compound;
```

Function is supposed to calculate one of the columns for the inserted row, and its input parameter is ID of the inserted row which I used to select that particular inserted row into record type before calculation with record type.

```
function                getJockerBroj
( i_igra_id             igra.id%type
)
return                  rezultat.jocker_broj%type
is
 v_jocker            rezultat.jocker_broj%type;
 rezultat_rec        brojevi_type; 
begin
select  br1
     , br2
     , br3
     , br4
     , br5
     , br6
     , br7
     ,dopunski_broj
into   rezultat_rec
from   rezultat
where  igra_id=i_igra_id;
v_jocker:=
      (  substr(to_char(rezultat_rec.br1),-1, 1) 
      || substr(to_char(rezultat_rec.br2),-1, 1) 
      || substr(to_char(rezultat_rec.br3),-1, 1)
      || substr(to_char(rezultat_rec.br4),-1, 1)
      || substr(to_char(rezultat_rec.br5),-1, 1)
      || substr(to_char(rezultat_rec.br6),-1, 1)
      || substr(to_char(rezultat_rec.br7),-1, 1)
      )
      ;    
 return v_jocker;
 end;
```

This apparently causes mutating table error, even though the function is called after insert on each row.

How can I get around this and make the calculation with each inserted row in that function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trigger (and any function called by the trigger) is not allowed to query the `rezultat` table since the trigger is a row-level defined on the `rezultat` table.  Doing so, as you've found, causes a mutating table exception.

Generally, you'd want to code your logic so that you are only referencing data from the `:new` pseudorecord.  In this case, for example, you could define your function to accept 7 parameters and pass those parameter values from your trigger.  Something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getJockerBroj (
  p_br1 in rezultat.br1%type,
  p_br2 in rezultat.br2%type,
  p_br3 in rezultat.br3%type,
  p_br4 in rezultat.br4%type,
  p_br5 in rezultat.br5%type,
  p_br6 in rezultat.br6%type,
  p_br7 in rezultat.br7%type
)
  RETURN rezultat.jocker_broj%type
IS
BEGIN
  RETURN substr(to_char(p_br1),-1, 1) 
      || substr(to_char(p_br2),-1, 1) 
      || substr(to_char(p_br3),-1, 1)
      || substr(to_char(p_br4),-1, 1)
      || substr(to_char(p_br5),-1, 1)
      || substr(to_char(p_br6),-1, 1)
      || substr(to_char(p_br7),-1, 1);
END;
```

Your trigger would then do something like

```
v_jck:=loto_7_47_pck.getJockerBroj(:new.br1, 
                                   :new.br2,
                                   :new.br3,
                                   :new.br4,
                                   :new.br5,
                                   :new.br6,
                                   :new.br7);
```

Comment: That works, but I have additional question. I have another procedure in the package that generates brX values and inserts them into REZULTAT accordingly. That procedure actually triggers insert trigger. Since that procedure (doGenerateValues) and function getJockerBroj are in the same package, is there a way to pass values of inserted brX from procedure to function? (like with cursors or records)

Comment: @user3885274 - Could you?  Sure, you can create a package global variable and use that to pass information around.  You definitely want to avoid that, however, because it makes your application very difficult to trace.  What are you doing with the result of the function?  Are you sure that you can't move the function call into your procedure rather than having it in the trigger?  Application logic in triggers often makes it difficult to follow the logic the application is implementing.